# Stumped - In Python obtaining unique keys with multiple associated values from a list of ditionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm parsing a csv file to perform some basic data processing. The file that I am working with is a log of user activity to a website formatted as follows:

```
User ID, Url, Number of Page Loads, Number of Interactions
```

User ID and Url are strings, Number of Page Loads and Number of Interactions are integers.

I am attempting to determine which url has the best interaction-to-page ratio.

The part I am struggling with is getting unique values and aggregating the results from the columns.

I've written the following code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

fields = ["USER","URL","LOADS","ACT"]

file = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv', 'rU'), delimiter=",",fieldnames=fields)
file.next()

dict = defaultdict(int)

for i in dict:
    dict[i['URL']] += int(i['LOADS'])
```

This works fine. It returns a list of unique urls with the number of total loads by url in a dictionary - `{ 'URL A' : 1000 , 'URL B' : 500}`

The issue is when i try to add multiple values to the url key, I'm stumped.

I've tried amending the for loop to do:

```
for i in dict:
    dict[i['URL']] += int(i['LOADS']), int(i['ACT'])
```

and I receive `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'`. Why is the second value considered a tuple?

I tried adding just `int(i[ACT])`, and it worked fine. It's just when I try both values at the same time.

I'm on python 2.6.7; Any ideas on how to do this and why it's considered a tuple?

Comment: What do you need to be the output like? `'URL A' : 1000 : 200`?

Comment: The output I'm trying to achieve is {'URL A' :( 1000, 100), 'URL B' : (500, 100)}. The first variable is loads, the second variable is actions.As the url appears many times in the file, i'm trying to aggregate the urls, and add the sum of all loads and actions for that url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a `list` as your defaultdict container:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
fields = ["USER","URL","LOADS","ACT"]

with open('file.csv', 'rU') as the_file:
    rows = csv.DictReader(the_file, delimiter=",",fieldnames=fields)
    rows.next()

    for row in rows:
        data = (int(row['LOADS']),int(row['ACT']))
        d[row['URL']].append(data)
```

Now you have

```
d['someurl'] = [(5,17),(7,14)]
```

Now you can do whatever sums you would like, for example, all the `loads` for a URL:

```
load_sums = {k:sum(i[0] for i in d[k]) for k in d}
```

Comment: Thanks dude! Making the container a list made it far easier to manipulate!

Answer (score 1):

Because `int(i['LOADS']), int(i['ACT'])` is a tuple:

```
>>> 1, 2
(1, 2)
```

If you want to add both variables at the same time, just add them together:

```
+= int(i['LOADS']) + int(i['ACT'])
```

Also, you're shadowing the builtin `dict` and `list` types. Use different variable names. You won't be able to use the `list` builtin once your shadow it:

```
>>> d = {1: 2, 3: 4}
>>> list(d)
[1, 3]
>>> list = 5
>>> list(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

*It's just when I try both values at the same time.*

How do you want to "add" them? As their sum?

```
for i in list:
    dict[i['URL']] += int(i['LOADS']) + int(i['ACT'])
```

Also, don't use `list` and `dict` as variable names.

```
import csv
fields = ["USER","URL","LOADS","ACT"]

d = {}
with open('file.csv', 'rU') as f:
    csvr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",",fieldnames=fields)
    csvr.next()
    for rec in csvr:
        d[rec['URL']] = d.get(rec['URL'], 0) + int(rec['LOADS']) + int(rec['ACT'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about list and dict. I see I also made a mistake when I copied the code above - it's 'for i in dict:' , not list. The output I'm trying to achieve is {'URL A' :( 1000, 100), 'URL B' : (500, 100)}. The first variable is loads, the second variable is actions.As the url appears many times in the file, i'm trying to aggregate the urls, and add the sum of all loads and actions for that url.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object-oriented approach and define a class to hold the information. It's wordier than most of the other answers, but worth considering.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

class Info(object):
    def __init__(self, loads=0, acts=0):
        self.loads = loads
        self.acts = acts
    def __add__(self, args): # add a tuple of values
        self.loads += args[0]
        self.acts += args[1]
        return self
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(loads={}, acts={})'.format(self.__class__.__classname__,
                                              self.loads, self.acts)

summary = defaultdict(Info)
fields = ["USER", "URL", "LOADS", "ACTS"]

with open('urldata.csv', 'rU') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fields)
    reader.next() # skip header
    for rec in reader:
        summary[rec['URL']] += (int(rec['LOADS']), int(rec['ACTS']))

for url,info in summary.items():
    print '{{{!r}: ({}, {})}}'.format(url, info.loads, info.acts)
```